# How to convert executed HQL Query to SQL Query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, spring-data

This is HQL query I am getting in Console. I am getting  "org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException" while Logging.I am usinng correct credentials while login. I am new to HQL query language. Need help thanks

```
--- HQL AST ---
     \-[QUERY] Node: 'query'
        +-[SELECT_FROM] Node: 'SELECT_FROM'
        |  +-[FROM] Node: 'from'
        |  |  \-[RANGE] Node: 'RANGE'
        |  |     +-[DOT] Node: '.'
        |  |     |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
        |  |     |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
        |  |     |  |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
        |  |     |  |  |  |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'com'
        |  |     |  |  |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'mindfiresolutions'
        |  |     |  |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'springmaven'
        |  |     |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'models'
        |  |     |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'Employee'
        |  |     \-[ALIAS] Node: 'generatedAlias0'
        |  \-[SELECT] Node: 'select'
        |     \-[IDENT] Node: 'generatedAlias0'
        \-[WHERE] Node: 'where'
           \-[EQ] Node: '='
              +-[DOT] Node: '.'
              |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'generatedAlias0'
              |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'employeeUserName'
              \-[COLON] Node: ':'
                 \-[IDENT] Node: 'param0'
```

Comment: and the exception has nothing to do with the JPQL being invoked, nor the JPA API ... just look at its stack trace and its message!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably exactly what it sounds like, you're using the wrong credentials to connect.  Without knowing more about your app (what kind or how you run it) it's hard to know for sure, but I recommend taking a look at your connection configuration to be sure everything is as it should be.

From api: BadCredentialsException is "Thrown if an authentication request is rejected because the credentials are invalid. For this exception to be thrown, it means the account is neither locked nor disabled."

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/BadCredentialsException.html